# Retrieve Json Data Using CURL PHP

Tags: php, json, get

Using CURL here we retrieve data and print then save to file after that insert it into database.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>"http://api.abc.com/v1/products/search.json?q=ball",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING =>"",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION =>true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION=>CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>"", 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> array(
        "authorization: AsiMemberAuth client_id=50041351&client_secret=55700485cc39f1",
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
    CURLOPT_HEADER=> true
);


curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err){
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

The Result json is fine. now i want to save it in json file?

Comment: you could remove `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>"", ` as they are superflous and contradict one another.

Comment: OK i will do that. thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

to save a string to a file in php, you can use file_put_contents()

[file_put_contents doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] ) : int
```

You can update your code as follows:

```
if ($err){
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;

    //Write response to file
    file_put_contents("my_file.json", $response)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice !! It's Done.